# Priority of Various Sources in PropertySources

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-4

`Spring` has introduced a new annotation `@PropertySources` for all classes marked as `@Configuration` since `4.0`. It takes different `@PropertySource` as argument.

```
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties"), @PropertySource("file:/tmp/application.properties")})
```

What I am interested is knowing is the ordering in case of conflict in values for the same key present in multiple properties file. I have not seen any documentation related to this that specifies an ordering. I have tries it multiple times and found that the `PropertySource` mentioned later is overwriting the value present in `PropertySource` mentioned before. But, how to be sure?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The documentation of [@PropertySources](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySources.html) does not say anything about the case where the same property exists in more than one @PropertySource files.

However, the documentation of @PropertySource states the following :

> In cases where a given property key exists in more than one
>   .properties file, the last @PropertySource annotation processed will
>   'win' and override

Since the @PropertySource declarations within @PropertySources are actually a table, then it is fairly safe to assume that the last declared @PropertySource overrides the previous ones. This is consistent with the tests I've done and with this [blog post](http://www.jayway.com/2014/02/16/spring-propertysource/).

However, as mentioned in the question, it is not indicated clearly in the documentation. So the behavior might "accidentally" change in the future.

Comment: btw, also interesting from there is "In certain situations, it may not be possible or practical to tightly control property source ordering when using \@ProperySource annotations. For example, if the \@Configuration classes above were registered via component-scanning, the ordering is difficult to predict. In such cases - and if overriding is important - it is recommended that the user fall back to using the programmatic PropertySource API. See ConfigurableEnvironment and MutablePropertySources javadocs for details."

Comment: Not much related to this, but I found useful to use a \@DependsOn("customPropertySourceBean") annotation in the classes using \@PropertySource in order to load programmatically the properties from a custom Property Source bean before the actual \@PropertySource classes were populated

Answer (score 5):

HL'REB is right. "Win" the parameter from the last properties file. However, application.properties overrides all values. Checked for SPRING 5.1.6.

Answer (score 3):

It seems likely that `@PropertySource` annotations inside of a `@PropertySources` annotation are processed in the order they appear, based on my tests, however if you [set up a listener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34434999/14193), they will print in reverse order.

**Annotations:**

```java
@Configuration
@PropertySources({
  @PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.global.properties"),
  @PropertySource(
      value = "classpath:application.client-specific.properties",
      ignoreResourceNotFound = true),
  @PropertySource(
      value = "file:/etc/omnia/application.client-specific.properties",
      ignoreResourceNotFound = true),
  @PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.test.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
})
```

**And the logging output:**

```
Loading @PropertySource: 'configurationProperties'
Loading @PropertySource: 'servletConfigInitParams'
Loading @PropertySource: 'servletContextInitParams'
Loading @PropertySource: 'systemProperties'
Loading @PropertySource: 'systemEnvironment'
Loading @PropertySource: 'random'
Loading @PropertySource: 'URL [file:/etc/omnia/application.client-specific.properties]'
Loading @PropertySource: 'class path resource [application.global.properties]'
```