# get name of the file loaded by @PropertySource

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties

Is there anyway I can know in my program, the full path of file loaded through @PropertySource annotation of Spring.
I need it to show in logs so that one can know which property file is being used in the application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below seems to be working, though I am not sure if the instance is always of type `ConfigurableEnvironment`

```
@Component
public class MyListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>{

  @Autowired
  private Environment env;

  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyListener.class);

  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {

    if(env instanceof ConfigurableEnvironment){
      MutablePropertySources propertySources = ((ConfigurableEnvironment)env).getPropertySources();
      for(PropertySource ps : propertySources){
        log.info(ps.getName());  //if only file based needed then check if instanceof ResourcePropertySource
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: don't really need all this. As already answered by Selim, enabling the proper logs does the trick

`log4j.logger.org.springframework.core.env.MutablePropertySources=DEBUG`

Comment: Where your `if` statement is written?

Comment: This can be in implementation class of ApplicationListener, so it gets logged after the context is initialized

Comment: Cool. Good to know. Thank your for the solution. +1

Answer (score 4):

This information is logged already by **StandardServletEnvironment**. You can set log level to **DEBUG** for  **org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment** class to show details in your logs.

If you use spring-boot you can simply add following line into your application.properties file.

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment = DEBUG
```

Comment: do we really need spring-boot? we can just have `log4j.logger.org.springframework.core.env.MutablePropertySources=DEBUG`

Comment: The class comes with spring-web, so if you use at least spring-web in your project, and set your logger configuration appropriately, so that this class' DEBUG logs pushed into the log appender, you theoretically don't need spring-boot.

Comment: My notice was only as an example how you can configure your logger, if you use spring-boot. But the solution is not depends on spring-boot

Answer (score 0):

in current ('21) versions of Spring Boot, neither of the two above suggestions for the logging level seem to work. moreover - if the file is actually NOT loaded, because it is NOT found or for whatever other reason, nothing is printed anyway.

at the moment when i have my ROOT logger set to DEBUG (logging.level.root=DEBUG in application.properties), the only thing I see in the log file, when the file is loaded correctly and the @Value annotated property is resolved successfully is:

> 2021-07-23 11:06:10.299 DEBUG 16776 --- [  restartedMain]
> o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of
> singleton bean 'bahblahService'
>
> 2021-07-23 11:06:10.302 DEBUG 16776 --- [  restartedMain]
> o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Found key
> 'blahblah.username' in PropertySource 'class path
> resource [custom-local.properties]' with value of type String